# Error reading or writing history file in PowerShell on Linux

Tags: rhel7, powershell-7.0

I've just had PS 7.0.2 installed on 2x boxes running RHEL 7.x (maipo). Oddly enough, one of them is showing the following error

```
    $ pwsh
    PS /home/user_name> dir
    Error reading or writing history file '/home/user_name/.local/share/powershell/PSReadLine/Console_history.txt': Access to the path '/home/user_name/.local/share/powershell/PSReadLine/Console_history.txt' is denied
    PS /home/user_name> exit
    Error reading or writing history file '/home/user_name/.local/share/powershell/PSReadLine/Console_history.txt': Access to the path '/home/user_name/.local/share/powershell/PSReadLine/Console_history.txt' is denied
    This error will not be reported again in this session. Consider using a different path with:
      Set-PSReadLineOption -HistorySavePath <Path>
    Or not saving history with:
      Set-PSReadLineOption -HistorySaveStyle SaveNothing
```

I can't figure out why. All I did was download the RPM and install it. And both the boxes are practically copies of each other :(

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Err .. just figured it out. It was an errant umask setting overriding the default in my ~/.bashrc.

Commenting it out solved the problem.